# Java: read serial port (baudrate 921600)

Tags: java, io, serial-port

I'm developing a Java software which has to be able to read some data sent by a device through a serial COM port, the speed of the communication is very important for me and so the baudrate is set to 921600.
In the beginning everything works fine (and so it reads the correct data that the device sends through the serial port) but after a while the software starts to read wrong data.
It seems like the software is too slow and it actually loses some of the data while they are coming into the input buffer (maybe when the input buffer is fully filled for the first time).
In order to speed up the reading operation I'm currently using a reading approach in which the software deals with as much bytes as possible per reading.
I've also tried to make the input buffer size bigger (by using the serialPort.setInputBufferSize(byte) method but it didn't solve my problem)
So has anyone ever done a fast serial communication with java? Am I missing something?
Why everything works fine for a while and then it stops to work properly?

This is my code for the reading part (even driven), please skip the part of the data conversion, that's just because every data is actually composed by 2 bytes and so I also have to compose them before the write them into a txt file.

```
/**
 *
 * @param evt
 */
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {

     switch(evt.getEventType()) {

        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            System.out.println("THE OUTPUT BUFFER IS EMPTY");
            break;

        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
            try {     

                while(SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE == 1) {


                   num_bytes = input.available();
                   array = new byte[num_bytes];

                   bytes_read = input.read(array, 0, num_bytes);

                   dato = new short[bytes_read];
                   datoc = new int[bytes_read/2];
                   datos = new String[bytes_read/2];


                   for(j=0;j<bytes_read;j++){                           
                       dato[j] = (short) (((byte) array[j]) & 0xff);
                   }

                   k = 0;
                   for(j=0;j<(bytes_read/2);j++){

                       datoc[j] = dato[k];
                       datoc[j] = (datoc[j]<<8) + dato[k+1];
                       datoc[j] = datoc[j] & 0xffffffff;  
                       k = k + 2;
                   }

                   for(j=0;j<(bytes_read/2);j++){

                       System.out.println(datoc[j]);
                       datos[j] = Integer.toString(datoc[j]);
                       output1.write(datos[j] + " ");
                   }

               }
            } catch(IOException ex) {
              logText = "Failed to read data. (" + ex.toString() + ")";
              System.out.println(logText);
            }
            break;

    }
```

Comment: How long is a while? If you can process the data for an hour before it fails, I would guess you might have a memory leak or that it fails while Java is doing garbage collection(Just guessing Java would does that). Also, is the serial event firing again before you finish processing the last event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that was slowing down the serial communication was the use of `System.out.println()`. Without that, the data receiving got eventually fine

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your program is failing to service the incoming data fast enough; it would work for a period of time because the input goes into a buffer, and as you empty the buffer there is more space for more input.  But if the data is coming in faster than you are processing it overall, eventually your buffer is full and data still comes in and has nowhere to go.  It was/is typical in serial communication for such data to get dumped on the (virtual) floor.

It is also typical for a status to be set indicating "buffer overflow".  First thing I would check is whether this status is available to you in whatever library you are using to read the serial data, and see if/when it gets set.  This would verify that the above is what's happening.

Another thing to check on, if it is reasonable in your environment, is XON/XOFF capability.  This was/is a feature of some serial communications allowing a receiver to indicate to a sender that its buffer was nearly full and to stop sending (XOFF) until told it was all right to begin again (XON).  Not all hardware and software supported this feature.

If that doesn't work for whatever reason and this is indeed the problem, you are going to have to do a better job of either processing your data faster or buffering it further.  A simple brute-force approach is to write the bytes to storage as they come in and read them in a separate thread.  If this is a traditional computer system, for instance, you can write them to disk and then process the disk file, opening it for read in one thread and writing in another (what fun!).

Comment: XON/XOFF is software flow control, so it doesn't relate to hardware support.  It is very uncommon to use XON/XOFF.  The much more common flow control solution is hardware RTS/CTS.  The vast majority of hardware supports RTS/CTS.

Comment: For XON/XOFF to be supported, there must be full-duplex; perhaps I'm reaching back into history too far -- I doubt there are many half-duplex systems out there -- but there really does need to be hardware support for the software to send the signals.  You are right that it is software-based, and I did forget to mention RTS/CTS -- OP should look at that, and I'm glad you mentioned it.